# "An access token is required to request this resource." while posting message to FB page using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to create one PHP application which ll post message to FB page directly. But facing some issues while posting message. I got following error:-

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

Following is my code:-

```
<?php 

    class Facebook
    {
        private $page_id = 'Page ID';   
        private $page_access_token = 'access-code';
        private $post_url = '';

        public function Facebook()
        {
            $this->post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$this->page_id.'/feed';
        }

        public function message($data)
        {
            $data['access_token'] = $this->page_access_token;
            $ch = curl_init();
            echo "Link:- ".$this->post_url;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->post_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $return = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $return;
        }
    }

    $facebook = new Facebook(); 
    $facebook->message(array( 'message'  => 'Best Service'));
    ?>
```

I tried alot to solve this error. I checked access token n page ID also both are correct but still getting this error.

Please guide me to solve this error....

Thanks in advance......